# How can I change the background color via a manual boolean input toggle in Pine?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script and try to change the background color of the chart based on a boolean, which I manually can turn true/false (real time) via the input settings. The background color should only change for the bars, where the boolean is true ([see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLvMM.png)).

```
bool dummy_toggle = input(title="dummy_toggle", type=input.bool, defval=false)
BgBool = false
if dummy_toggle == true
    BgBool := true
bgcolor(color=BgBool ? color.lime : na, transp=85)
```

The mistake I probably make is that I don't appoint the bool value to a specific bar[series]. I don't know how to fix this. Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are moving in the right direction.
The script in your case should be something like this.

```
bool dummy_toggle = input(title="dummy_toggle", type=input.bool, defval=false)
BgBool = false
if condition_for_background_color == true
    BgBool := true
bgcolor(color=(dummy_toggle and BgBool)? color.lime : na, transp=85)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this still does not give the result I would like to have. This script is changing the background color of all bars to 'color.lime', while I intend to only change the color for the specific bars where my 'dummy toggle' was true.

Comment: To give an exact answer, you need the full text of a working script. Happy New Year!

Comment: See my answer above.

Comment: I didn't think you would take me so literally.
You must have a logical expression in place of the "trade_on_off_switch == true" (e.g. crossing lines), which will change the background.

Comment: I understand that you need a logical expression for this. This is straightforward when you evaluate the data. But I don't know how to do this for an input switch that needs to be evaluated each bar.

Comment: If my second answer did not help you, then I did not understand your question.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it correctly. Maybe it's more clear when I break my problems in 2 parts:
1. I want to track an input variable (a boolean in this case) over time.
2. Based on this input variable I want to change the background, similar to what your code is doing.

Comment: Do you want to remember your mouse clicks and change the background on the chart? I am not an expert, but this is not possible.
Surely, you want to tag the bars that you see with your own eyes and analyze with your intellect. Try to translate this into boolean conditions. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I will try to find a workaround for this. I'm suprised that such basic functionality is not available in Pine. Anyway, many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Happy New Year too!

Here is my sample code:

```
//@version=4
study("Test_Trade-ON-OFF-switch_bgcolor", overlay = true)

//GENERAL VARIABLES
//switch to manually turn the active trading ON and OFF
bool trade_on_off_switch = input(title="dummy_trade_on_off_switch", type=input.bool, defval=false)

//color background green for bars where active trading is ON (i.e. trade_on_off_switch == true)
color plotColor = color.white
BgBool = false
if trade_on_off_switch == true
    BgBool := true
bgcolor(color=(trade_on_off_switch and BgBool)? color.green : na, transp=85)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works.

```
//@version=4
study("Test_Trade-ON-OFF-switch_bgcolor", overlay = true)

//GENERAL VARIABLES
//switch to manually turn the active trading ON and OFF
bool trade_on_off_switch = input(title="dummy_trade_on_off_switch", type=input.bool, defval=true)

//color background green for bars where active trading is ON (i.e. trade_on_off_switch == true)
color plotColor = color.white
p = stoch(close, high, low, 14)
BgBool = false
if cross(p, 50) // e.g. crossing stochastic with level 50 
    BgBool := true

hline(50,color=color.black)
bgcolor(color=(trade_on_off_switch and BgBool)? color.green : na, transp=50)
plot(p, color=color.blue)
```